# I'm trying to figure out how to turn a creation (designated area) into falling blocks with the correct blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've found a YouTube video on how to make sand block entities look like glass, wool, or stairs, etc. I wanted to try and make some sort of creation with it, but the process I came up with involved typing in the name of the block I want it to look like and then placing a bunch of command blocks.

I'm trying to find a system that takes a designated area, scans the blocks to find out exactly what they are (what block, how it's rotated) and places the falling_block entity.

This is what I have for placing the falling_block entity:

```
summon falling_block ~ ~2 ~ {BlockState:{Name:"minecraft:redstone_block"},Time:1,NoGravity:1b}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Cloud Wolf's Block ID packager](https://cloudwolfyt.github.io/pages/gens/block-id.html). It is a powerful tool that gives every single block and all of it's possible block states an ID. You will need a datapack to use this.

If you have questions, you can ask on his discord (invite link on the Home tab)

---

To perform this action on every single block in a specified volume, you will need a block searching algorithm, that can scan a specified volume of blocks dynamically. Cloud Wolf also has a tutorial on this, here:

The basic method is to use a recursive function that increases/decreases a score every time it runs, until the score reaches a set limit. Essentially, you make a for loop.

This function will move forward 1 block each time, using `execute positioned ~ ~1 ~`. You will need to perform this looping action multiple times for each axis (xyz)

Comment: Do you think there's a way to tag the entities depending on where they are relative to a point? If I, for example, wanted to turn the block ~3 ~2 ~-1 from an armorstand into a fallingsand, and then tag it with [~3 ~2 ~-1].

Comment: You will need a block searching algorithm, that can scan a specified volume of blocks dynamically. Cloud Wolf also has a tutorial on this, here: https://youtu.be/mjn1Y60QcZg